# Why do we use composer,nodejs and gulp when using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

What is the real purpose of installing composer and node.js, and the npm install?

Comment: what do you mean by non install?

Comment: Composer is a package manager for PHP. It installs the various parts Laravel needs to run, and is the accepted standard for modern PHP. Node isn't strictly required, but it's useful for the optional (but handy) Laravel Mix and a few other bits of tooling.

Comment: What is the problem you have with these things?

Comment: @kRicha sorry it's npm install

Comment: @castis I did all of this without knowing the purpose of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. composer is the dependency manager for php laravel framework. Look at this link for more infomation on this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_installation.htm
2. Node js : like @ceejayoz said, it is not mandatory for laravel but may be needed to hook up some external tools.
3. If by non install you meant npm install, npm is the package manager for node js (npm stands for nodejs package manager). This is a tool that lets you install several packages that work with nodejs. According to the npm website, npm lets you discover and re-use over 470,000 free code packages in the npm Registry.